# How to get the Operating System of the user using Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I followed this [guide](https://datapythonista.me/blog/getting-client-os-in-django.html) trying to get user agent from request

specifically the Operating System
Obviously I cannot use the normal way of getting the operating system which is using the os module with python but that won't work because the operating system will be the one hosting the server

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPALTES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myproject.myapp.context_processors.user_agent',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

cannot do that. it claims that I don't have a myproject.myapp module

Comment: try this: https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the user agent from a request you can use this in a view:

```
agent = request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

Then you can use something like [`httpagentparser`](http://shon.github.io/httpagentparser/) to get the OS:

```
import httpagentparser
agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
s = httpagentparser.detect(agent)["os"]
```